# Matplotlib doesn't draw data from one column

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

Here' the dataframe I have

[image: Dataframe]

I try to draw a plot with Sample Size as x-axis and the rest of the columns as y-axis

Here's my code:

```
df.plot(x='Sample Size',y=df.columns[:-1])
```

I have also tried Seaborn:

```
dfm = df.melt('Sample Size', var_name='Metrics', value_name='vals')
        
g = sns.catplot(x='Sample Size', 
                y='vals', 
                hue='Metrics', 
                data=dfm, 
                kind='point',
                height=6.27, 
                aspect=8.27/6.27)
```

However that is what I get

[image: Plot]

And same for point plot in Seaborn.

As you can see the Sensitivity data isn't drawn.

There is no NaN values and I tried to reset index in case it was the fault. I really don't know why it does that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your columns `sensitivity` and `specificity` contain the same values. The curves are drawn on top of each other, so you only see one.

Comment: Brilliant, I am an idiot. I thought about this option but for some reason overlooked it.

Comment: You can see why by changing the type of graph to a bar graph.

Comment: Yes, I have used inbuilt scikit recall_Score function and chose incorrect positive label, so my sensitivity was actually my specificity. Sorted it now. Thanks.